# How do I edit C# method at runtime using IL on .net framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, methods, runtime, .net-3.5, cil

I have seen many threads about it but none of the solutions worked for me.

How can I edit a C# method using IL on .NET Framework 3.5? I need to edit the code of a Unity (and Unity Web Player) game at runtime by injecting an external assembly.

I have tried using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time

The solution mentioned before throws an exception ("error System.Exception: Failed to get addresses from server, Timeout was reached") on initialization.

Comment: You're going to need to flesh that question out a bit.  What are you trying to do?  Why are you trying to do it?  What have you tried?  What didn't work when you tried it?

Comment: Added the needed information.

Comment: And the exception is?  My guess is that it's a file IO exception, indicating that the assembly is locked once it is loaded.  Why would you want to do this?  Is this your assembly?  Is it strongly named?  What environment are you running in (desktop, web, etc.)?

Comment: Desktop, It can't be an IO exception because the assembly is in the memory, It isn't strongly named. The exception message is `error System.Exception: Failed to get addresses from server, Timeout was reached.`

Comment: Can you please provide your code and the exceptions stacktrace?

Comment: `error System.Exception: Failed to get addresses from server, Timeout was reached.
in InjectionHelper.WaitForInitializationCompletion() in C:\Users\PiotrKFtw\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\RuntimeUnityHook\RuntimeUnityHook\InjectionHelper.cs
line 121
in RuntimeUnityHook.TestClass.Hook()
 in C:\Users\PiotrKFtw\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\RuntimeUnityHook\RuntimeUnityHook\Loader.cs:line 26`